# Is there a way to make iPhone classes closed for editing and observing

Tags: iphone, components

I have classes we wrote for one of our customers, to be used in their own iPhone code.

We would like to make the classes sealed for observing and prevent the code from being copied like we would do in Windows by a closed DLL or compiled SWF in Flash.

Is there a way to do the same for iPhone classes?

Comment: Why not give them the code if they paid for it to be developed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can compile your code to a library file, such as a .a, and then require them to link in your compiled library.

See a related helpful Q&A: [A Guide for Creating your own Library for Cocoa(touch) development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681485/a-guide-for-creating-your-own-library-for-cocoatouch-development)