# Could I extend Corona with native code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, lua, coronasdk

I have some function module written in Objective-c, could i wrap the objective-C by C++, then integrate C/C++ code with Lua using toLua++, then using the lua code in Corona? Could i do that? It seems impossible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make a shared library, then just require it into your code.

e.g. create mylibrary.so

then in lua

```
require("mylibrary")
```

lua will look for it in your LUA_PATH.

There are a few things I'm not sure of in corona - if it will load a shared library and you can use toLUa++. It will work fine in normal lua. You might have problems with bindings in the shared library to Cocoa - not sure, not something I've tried. I've built a .dll in windows and it worked fine - again not in corona.

[Here's how to build a shared library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

[It seems like corona will do it - have a look here](http://howto.oz-apps.com/2011/08/dynamic-loading.html)

[this could be the stopper though - no shared libraries on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389856/how-can-i-create-objective-c-framework-for-ios-application)

hth

Comment: But the key problem is IN CORONA. -_-!

Comment: yah but corona is lua with some libraries as far as I understand. The kicker is that you can't have shared libraries on iOS, unless someones figured out a hack. You could conceivably make your own corona shell and statically link your library, this would be hard :-(

Comment: @daven11: [Not all parts of Lua are included.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/changes-lua). `require` is preprocessed when you "build", I believe (with Corona, you have to submit your code to their servers to get back a working app).

Answer (score 2):

Corona doesn't allow extending with native code (yet) 
It is in their roadmaps, and it is supposed to be implemented in coming months

Comment: Almost 3 years later, I am wondering if this has been implemented?