# Can I convert my iPhone application to an API?

Tags: iphone, ios4, static-libraries

I have an iPhone application which should be converted to an library, so that I can use it as an API.

How do I do this so that other applications can also use it? (API).

Comment: Is the iPhone application fetching data from a server?

Comment: yes i do get data from server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389856/how-can-i-create-objective-c-framework-for-ios-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way

Answer (score 0):

You have to read a bit about the [static libraries](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/). It's easy.